# Some maths about camera in 3D

Tags: opengl, c++, raylib

So after finishing a 2d game for my school project, I decided to dive into 3d world by using raylib instead of Unity. Raylib does provide a simple implementation of 3d camera without you doing maths, but instead I want to challenge myself to understand trigonometry in 3d.Here, I am trying to make the camera rotate upside down and left right(like it's orbiting). After implementing the math, it seems like it only works when the target is at Vector3{0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f} position. If the target position gets further and further, the rotation gets weird. Here is the demonstration video that I uploaded to youtube.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MpXkhGy60HA&feature=youtu.be

And below is my code for math:

```
Vector3 cubePosition = { 0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f };

Camera3D camera = { 0 };

camera.position = { 0.0f, 10.0f, 10.0f }; // Camera position

camera.target = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f }; // Camera looking at point

camera.up = { 0.0f,2.0f, 0.0f }; // Camera up vector (rotation towards target)

camera.fovy = 45.0f; // Camera field-of-view Y

float distance = 15.0f; // Set the distance from camera.target to camera.position

float verticalAngle = 45.0f; // The Y/XZ angle

float horizontalAngle = 90.0f; // The X/Z angle, y is considered as 0

float horizontalDistance = distance * cosf(verticalAngle * PI / 180.0f); // Horizontal distance, the magnitude

camera.position.x = horizontalDistance * cosf(horizontalAngle * PI / 180.0f); // Calculate the position of camera.position x based on distance etc..

camera.position.z = horizontalDistance * sinf(horizontalAngle * PI / 180.0f);

camera.position.y = distance * sinf(verticalAngle * PI / 180.0f);

Vector3 selectedTarget = cubePosition;
```

And for the main loop :

```
if (IsKeyDown(KEY_A))

{

camera.position.x = horizontalDistance * cosf(horizontalAngle * PI / 180.0f);

camera.position.z = horizontalDistance * sinf(horizontalAngle * PI / 180.0f);

horizontalAngle -= 1.0f;

}

else if (IsKeyDown(KEY_D))

{

camera.position.x = horizontalDistance * cosf(horizontalAngle * PI / 180.0f);

camera.position.z = horizontalDistance * sinf(horizontalAngle * PI / 180.0f);

horizontalAngle += 1.0f;

}

else if (IsKeyDown(KEY_W) && verticalAngle < 88.0f)

{

horizontalDistance = distance * cosf(verticalAngle * PI / 180.0f);

camera.position.x = horizontalDistance * cosf(horizontalAngle * PI / 180.0f);

camera.position.z = horizontalDistance * sinf(horizontalAngle * PI / 180.0f);

camera.position.y = distance * sinf(verticalAngle * PI / 180.0f);

verticalAngle += 1.0f;

}

else if (IsKeyDown(KEY_S) && verticalAngle > 2.0f)

{

horizontalDistance = distance * cosf(verticalAngle * PI / 180.0f);

camera.position.x = horizontalDistance * cosf(horizontalAngle * PI / 180.0f);

camera.position.z = horizontalDistance * sinf(horizontalAngle * PI / 180.0f);

camera.position.y = distance * sinf(verticalAngle * PI / 180.0f);

verticalAngle -= 1.0f;

}

if (IsKeyPressed(KEY_RIGHT))

{

camera.position.x += 1.0f;

selectedTarget.x += 1.0f;

}

else if (IsKeyPressed(KEY_LEFT))

{

camera.position.x -= 1.0f;

selectedTarget.x -= 1.0f;

}

if (IsKeyPressed(KEY_UP))

{

camera.position.z -= 1.0f;

selectedTarget.z -= 1.0f;

}

else if (IsKeyPressed(KEY_DOWN))

{

camera.position.z += 1.0f;

selectedTarget.z += 1.0f;

}

if (IsKeyPressed(KEY_SPACE))

{

cubeList.push_back(selectedTarget);

}

camera.target = selectedTarget;
```

Since raylib is using opengl so i tried to use the following link and picture to understand the camera system.
https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Camera

This is the picture I used to calculate my camera position.
https://uploads.disquscdn.com/images/58fa1f1a3dd8d736a9345b3b168dd55caf0f14d485e9dae7e06b8e185348a42a.png

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you..

Comment: Looks like you forgot to offset your camera position by the target position. You're always orbiting around (0, 0, 0) instead of orbiting your target.

Comment: Any reason you don't want to use the LookAt method, that was specifically made for this use case?

Comment: @DMGregory I did something like( camera.position.x -= 1.0f; selectedTarget.x -= 1.0f;) when moving left or right. The camera is always look at the target at the end of the main loop.

Comment: @thalm I am using raylib, a library that use opengl and has its own abstraction layer. Although I do know that I still can use opengl but I am still new to this.

Comment: += doesn't do a lot of good when you override it with just plain = when doing your trig calculations. ;)